# Is a Mode S transponder required as part of TCAS I?

Tags: transponder, tcas, mode-s

Is a Mode S transponder required as part of TCAS I?

Comment: I assume you are asking if the aircraft with TCAS I installed must also have a Mode S transponder installed as well since that is a requirement of TCAS II?